# How to execute a command within a controller of a Symfony2 application and print in real-time the output in a Twig template

Tags: php, symfony, real-time, symfony-process

I need to execute a long-lasting command within a controller of my Symfony2 application and to return to the user in real time the output of the terminal.

I have read this:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#getting-real-time-process-output

I can't figure out how to print in real time the terminal output in a Twig template.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the Matteo's code and users comments, the final implementation is:

```
/**
 * @Route("/genera-xxx-r", name="commission_generate_r_xxx")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 */
public function generateRXXXsAction()
{
    //remove time constraints if your script last very long
    set_time_limit(0);        

    $rFolderPath = $this->container->getParameter('xxx_settings')['r_setting_folder_path'];
    $script = 'R --slave -f ' . $rFolderPath . 'main.R';

    $response = new StreamedResponse();
    $process = new Process($script);
    $response->setCallback(function() use ($process) {
        $process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
            //if you don't want to render a template, please refer to the @Matteo's reply
            echo $this->renderView('AppBundle:Commission:_process.html.twig',
                array(
                    'type' => $type,
                    'buffer' => $buffer
                ));
            //according to @Ilmari Karonen a flush call could fix some buffering issues
            flush();
        });
    });
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: you need to launch and intercept a shell script or a symfony command task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need lo launch a simple shell script and capture the output, you can use a [StreamedResponse](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/introduction.html#streaming-a-response) in conjunction with the `Process` callback you posted.

As Example, suppose you have a very simple bash script like follow:

**loop.sh**

```
for i in {1..500}
do
   echo "Welcome $i times"
done
```

You can implement your action like:

```
/**
 * @Route("/process", name="_processaction")
 */
public function processAction()
{
    // If your script take a very long time:
    // set_time_limit(0);
    $script='/path-script/.../loop.sh';
    $process = new Process($script);

    $response->setCallback(function() use ($process) {
        $process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
            if (Process::ERR === $type) {
                echo 'ERR > '.$buffer;
            } else {
                echo 'OUT > '.$buffer;
                echo '<br>';
            }
        });
    });
    $response->setStatusCode(200);
    return $response;
}
```

And depends on the buffer length you can have an output like:

```
.....
OUT > Welcome 40 times Welcome 41 times 
OUT > Welcome 42 times Welcome 43 times 
OUT > Welcome 44 times Welcome 45 times 
OUT > Welcome 46 times Welcome 47 times 
OUT > Welcome 48 times 
OUT > Welcome 49 times Welcome 50 times 
OUT > Welcome 51 times Welcome 52 times 
OUT > Welcome 53 times 
.....
```

You can wrap this in a portion of a page with a render controller as example:

```
<div id="process">
    {{ render(controller(
        'AcmeDemoBundle:Test:processAction'
    )) }}
</div>
```

More info [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers)

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you very much. It works but I would like to pass the output to a Twig template. If I pass the entire response to the template I have not the same result described above. Can you help me please?

Comment: You want to render the process output with a twig files or you want to return a response that twig will render for you?

Comment: I want to return a response that twig render for me. I'm sorry but I realized that your example print the output at the end of the bash script execution. I would like to print the output _during_ the script execution... Because the script can last more than 30 minutes!

Comment: Sorry @Gianluca78 but the outout is rendered *during*  the execution: see the `OUT` . You can use the template engine into the renderer function and/or use this action as a render_controller twig block.

Comment: Hi @Gianluca78 I update my answer hope this clarify my intent

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. There is a little problem. Using the template as in your example produces an output like the following: HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date:          Mon, 23 Mar 2015 16:19:54 GMT

> Welcome 1 times
Welcome 2 times
Welcome 3 times
Welcome 4 times
Welcome 5 times
Welcome 6 times
Welcome 7 times
Welcome 8 times
<br>HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Date:          Mon, 23 Mar 2015 16:19:54 GMT

> Welcome 9 times

Comment: Ok, I have fixed it. Please replace in your answer the render method with the renderView one. By the way, it worked but I don't know why I have not real time output. Messages are displayed only at the end of the script execution.

Comment: Ok i revert to the previous version (without twig) I don't undestand why you have a syncronus response, i post a *working*  example may depend of the buffer size? Try dumping a lot of data....

Comment: @Gianluca78 if you post your code is more easy for me to help you... let me know

Comment: @Gianluca78: For the buffering issue, a simple [flush()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php) after the echo *might* fix it, assuming there are no other buffering layers involved.

Comment: @Matteo Thank you for your explanation ! I still have some issues with the template rendering, could you help me ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49328153/how-to-correctly-use-streamedresponse-and-realtime-output